# How to make 4 divs like zigzags in small devices?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have 4 `div` next to each other and inside my `div` I have some texts and the image. In desktop mode the `div` are next to each other, which is exactly what I want but in smaller device I want my 4 `div` to be like a zigzag. I really have a hard time fixing it. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 width-50 fixedMobile">
    <div style="min-height:400px !important;" class="service-details text-center">
      <img alt="image" class="services-image" height="180" width="180" src="images/design.jpg">

      <h4><a href="services#Design">title</a></h4><br>
      <p>some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 width-50 fixedMobile">
    <div style="min-height:400px !important;" class="service-details text-center">
      <img alt="image" class="services-image" height="180" width="180" src="images/maintenance.jpg">

      <h4><a href="services#Maintenance">title2</a></h4><br>
      <p>some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 mt-25 fixedMobile">
    <div style="min-height:400px !important;" class="service-details text-center">
      <img alt="image" class="services-image" height="180" width="180" src="images/buil.jpg">
      <h4><a href="services#seo">title3</a></h4><br>
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 mt-25 fixedMobile">
    <div style="min-height:400px !important;" class="service-details text-center">
      <img alt="image" class="services-image" height="180" width="180" src="images/managed.jpg">
      <h4><a href="#">Title</a></h4><br>
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is a ziczac?

Comment: Hi @DirkJ.Faber 
plz check following link
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/Regular_zig-zag.svg

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand your desired result. Do you want 4 divs next to each other but every other div has a bigger top margin?

Comment: sorry for that.I want my four divs looks like a zic zac in mobiles or tablets but in desktop i want them be next each other

Comment: You need to reorder the columns using `order-*` classes. I do not understand what you mean by `zic-zac`, otherwise I would have helped you. I think  you should explain what you mean by `zic zac`.